# disable all previous created button except current one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this delegated event handler function in jquery in my application.
and its working fine.Now I want to desable all the button already created except current one.

How do i do that

```
$('#form').on('click', '.button', function(){
var temp = '<input type="button" class="button" />'
$('#form').append(temp);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inserting the new button:

```
var temp = $('<input type="button" class="button" />');
$('#form').append(temp);
$('#form .button').not(temp).prop('disabled', true);
```

Please note that I added `$()` around the definition of the button so it's an element and not a HTML string (which would not work in `.not()`).

Alternatively you can also run this before inserting the button:

```
$('#form .button').prop('disabled', true);
```

That disables all buttons - but since the new one is not part of the form yet it won't be disabled

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $form = $('#form').on('click', '.button', function(){
    $form.find('.button').prop('disabled', true)
    var temp = '<input type="button" class="button" />'
    $form.append(temp);
})
```

Comment: @SaurabhSinha can you share the relevant html of the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form').on('click', '.button', function(){
    var temp = '<input type="button" class="button" />'
     $("#form").find(".button").prop("disabled",true).end().append(temp);
})
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` - and `siblings` might or might not work depending on the structure of the form.